# How to apply Spring Security AntMatchers pattern only to url with pathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring boot and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure security.

Method to configure ignored security antMatches looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/items")
           .antMatchers("/items/{itemId}")
```

where `{itemId}` is in UUID format

The issues is that with this configuration endpoints like`/items/report`, `/items/images` are also opened, but they should not.

Is there a way to apply ignoring rule only to uri with path variables ?

Comment: How is the framework suppose to know the difference between `/items/report` or `/items/images` and `/items/{itemId}`? How will it know that `report` or  `images` is not a value for `itemId` in the route `/items/{itemId}`? You would have to first declare a restriction for every _not-allowed-value_ such as `/items/report` and `/items/images` and then permit  `/items/{itemId}`.

Comment: For the rest request patteren, you need to put authenicated, like .antMatchers("/items/report").authenticated()

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, d represent itemId

```java
antMatchers("/items/{\\d+}").access("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE')")
```

if you want to give permit all

```java
antMatchers("/items/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: Your answer is not that helpful, because the question isn't about `HttpSecurity` it is about `WebSecurity`. There isn't any method like `acess` or `permitAll`. Using `\d` assumes that the ID is a digit, but OP didn't wrote anything about the format of the ID.

Comment: will ** work for any number of value like "item/a/b/c" ??

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html), you need to specify the path variable with the regex as per documentation:

> {spring:[a-z]+} matches the regexp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring".

In your case it will be:

```
@Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/items/{itemId:[\\d+]}")
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong, format of the `itemId` is UUID. Change your reqex to improve your answer.

Comment: I think only regex needs to be changed.But the logic that it passes only paths having   itemId as path variable is correct.So @dur you cannot say it is wrong answer. Rest regex for UUID or any other pattern can be searched easily.

Comment: Then remove the part beginning with *In your case it will be:* It implies, that you already searched the right reqex.

Answer (score 0):

For more sophisticated matching, than an Ant pattern can do, use method based security on your controller or (better) service layer methods.

Comment: Your answer is not that helpful, because the question is about `WebSecurity` and ignoring URLs. If you use method security, you can't ignore the URLs, the URLs have to go through the filter chain.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @preAuthorize annotation on the handler method for that url in the controller or check out this link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html